# POSIX representation of dates

Tags: datetime, r, file-io, posix, time-series

I am trying to use the R timeSeries package in order to read csv files.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
prices <- readSeries(file='A2006-2011.csv',head=T,sep=",",format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

However, it doesn't recognize the date in the csv (below are the first few lines of it)

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj.Close
4/4/2011    45.07   45.41   44.36   44.83   2133900 44.83
4/1/2011    44.88   45.48   44.78   45.14   2212300 45.14
3/31/2011   44.92   45.02   44.46   44.78   2194900 44.78
3/30/2011   44.79   45.17   44.65   45.09   2514100 45.09
```

and it prints the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In readSeries(file = "A2006-2011.csv", head = T, sep = ",", format = "%m/%d/%Y") :
  Conversion of timestamps to timeDate objects produced only NAs.
  Are you sure you provided the proper format with argument 'format'
  or in the header of your file ?
```

I will really appreciate it if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Is it correct that you're using comma as the field separator even though there appear to be no commas in your file?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would just read the table in with the `Date` as strings, then do a quick conversion. For example,

```
> x = c("4/4/2011", "4/4/2011", "3/31/2011", "3/30/2011")
## In your case you would have prices$Date = as.Date(prices$Date, ...
> as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2011-04-04" "2011-04-04" "2011-03-31" "2011-03-30"
```

Comment: Thanks to you I actually figured it out. Even though the dates in the file appear to be ""4/4/2011", when you read it into R they become "2011-04-04". So if anyone encouters the same problem with csv data files downloaded from yahoo, the right way to input format date is format="%Y-%m-%d".

Answer (score 0):

Try this package: speedR at https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/speedr. It is a visual data importer and support Date and POSIXct classes. Also you can use it to filter the existing R objects from the workspace visually.